# How to make vertical text change into horizontal text in css?

Tags: html, css

I am just working at an CMS site...but just got into a problem that the slider had text been written first in horizantal one line and now it shows into vertical text per word in every line like in a continuous way...so I am really wondering that what's happening the text to be showed in vertical form instead of horizontal form..so friends any help please...anyone who can tell or findout the real issue..!

The Text Is : "Serving Over 40 Years"

Here it's HTML Code :

```
<div class="txt2">Serving Over 40 Years</div>
```

While here it's CSS code :

```
.slider .txt2{ 
 width:100%; 
 height:30px;  
 z-index:11;  
 font-family:'NeouThin';
 font-size:30px; 
 line-height:30px; 
 color:#000000;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
 }
```

Here is slider class CSS code please :

```
.slider {
position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:6;
display: block;
width:975px;
height:537px;
overflow:visible!important;
}
```

And Here is live link to the site please : http://www.huntedhunter.com/raymain_errors/

waiting for your replies..thanks..

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `white-space: nowrap;` to the `txt2` class and it works.

Awesome picture slider btw !

Comment: Thanks..man it worked...! so you did the magic to solve my issue..Also besides thanks for your opinion on picture slider.!

Answer (score 0):

You should set your height to auto like this:

```
.slider .txt2{height: auto /*Rest of CSS Code*/}
```

Comment: Hey..! Thanks..for your answer...I have changed height to auto but still it's not showing up in horizontal line..!

Comment: @UmairShah Please post the CSS for the "slider" class

Comment: Question updated please for Slider class CSS code...please check it..!

Answer (score 0):

The parent element of that text `<div style="position:absolute; left:50%; top :-20%;">` has a width of 0 pixels, since it has not a defined width and a `position: absolute`. If you define the width for this element, say a width of 200px, the inner element with the text will  have this width.

Comment: I gave width of 200px to the parent div but still nothing happened?

Comment: Whoops, that value was just out of my head... If you set it to 50%, it will be the full width from the middle to the right edge. You can move it around, just keep the left and width values add to 100%, eg. `left:60%; width: 40%`